# Ignore sub directories with a specific name (and their contents) in project when searching in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I've been delving into some Android development lately.

Since I'm used to software that actually functions somewhat acceptably, I'm going to describe the ignore pattern, in Git, and a whole host of other software. What I want to ignore when searching in Android Studio (`Ctrl+Shift+F`) is:
`**/build/**`

I.e I want to ignore *all* files that live *under* a build directory - no matter where that build directory is.

I could not find answers about this on Stack Overflow.

Introducing a scope with `!file:build//*` or `!file:*/build//*` or `!file:**/build//*` or any permutation thereof, does not work. It will still hand me back things that live under a `/build/` directory somewhere.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android Studio, but just a thought - could you get your build process to put stuff in a sub-folder outside of your project folder? That would effectively avoid the problem rather than solve it, but it might produce the result you want.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's an open source project. And even worse, it's using the JVM-ecosystem.